# How do I show data in php without using echo or print

Tags: php, show

I would like to know if there's another way to do show data in client side, like laravel does using templates, by example;

In laravel we must to do it like this:

```
<?php

the result of  {{ $a }} + {{ $b }} is equals to {{ $c }}

?>
```

how could I do that but without using a framework?

ps: I can use echo, print, var_dump, etc. but I don't want to, I wish there's a different way, something more elegant.

Comment: Why can't you use echo or print?

Comment: i can use it, but i dont want to, i want to do it like laravel but without using a framework.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult, but it sounds like what you want IS a framework. And if not, then sounds like you want to build one yourself, including a templating engine. Your code could be how you write your templates, but you need PHP to insert your variables and output generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Other than echo and print, you can try to use var_dump() in PHP to flush out all your variables